# Why aren't Swift classes hashable by default?

Tags: swift, class

Classes have an identity and their hashValue could easily be their address in the memory. Why isn't it so?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the hash/digest of an object should be based on its contents, not its identity or address - and if an object has "irrelevant" state (e.g. cached values) then it should not be part of the hash calculation, but the Swift compiler doesn't know this. If a hash-value was based on an object's address then a runtime that uses memory-defragmentation (like the CLR, which will move objects in memory during GC pauses) would be fundamentally incompatible with Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's simply not very useful to have `hashValue` based on identity.

Here's an example:

Say I'm combining two sets of data from two different sources and checking for duplicates. A common way to do that is to add both to a `Set`. These objects will most certainly have unique identities (i.e. different addresses). If that implied they also had unique `hashValue`s, then none of the duplicates will be detected.

The whole reason using a `Set` for reduplication works in the first place is because `hashValue` implies a definition for what a duplicate is. Your proposal would break this.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand why it's not prudent to rely on object identity? If an object is allocated on the heap its pointer is, in effect, its identity. It seems necessary and reasonable to assume this, no?

Comment: Yep, the memory address of an object is indeed its identity. (for example, that's why the operator which compares references (`===` is called the "identical-to operator"). But we're talking about something different here. Let `S` be the set of all instances of type `T`. The Swift equality operator (`==`) is an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) (indeed, the most obvious example of one), which can be used to partition `S` into [equivalence classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class).

Comment: When two instances `a` and `b` are members of the same equivalence class, that's indicated by `a == b` returning `true`. If `c` is in a different equivalence class to `a` and `b`, then `a == c` and `a== c` will both return `false`. By conflating object identity with object equality, you're essentially partitioning your set `S` into `|S|` (means "size of S") different partitions, where each instance (each object) is the sole member of its equivalence class (since it is the only object with that reference, and every other reference is different).

Comment: It's very useful two have 2 different instances (i.e. different identity) which compare equally. I can't think of any situations in which it's useful to guarantee that no two non-identical objects must compare as unequal. Besides, if you really wanted an operator for the equality of identities, you already have it in `===`. `==` intentionally exists as a separate concept, an operator that "merges" the equivalence classes previously, into new large equivalence classes with multiple members each, which share some particular property.

Comment: All that being said, I didn't really talk about `hashValue`, because equality is a more simple way to talk about this. `hashValue` is just a heuristic for equality. If two objects have the same hashValues, there's a higher chance that they'll compare equally than just any other objects (with differing hashValues). When searching for an object in a collection by a hash, hashing lets you cull out large parts of the collection so you don't need to do equality checks against all elements. Instead, you only need to do equality checks against the set of objects with the same hashValues.

Comment: So then how do you define a set of objects that guarantees uniqueness in terms of identity? You would insert the same object twice. Two people called Jim with the age of 30 would be equal, and one would never be inserted into the set.

Comment: @MH175 My exact point is that "defin[ing] a set of objects that guarantees uniqueness in terms of identity" is almost never useful. Modelling identity of a person  by leaning on the reference identity is a poor idea. For one, how do you persist that to a database, or send it over an API? Are you going to encode a new field, the "identity" that's set to the pointer value? How is the other side going to make use of that? It can't. You would need a `personID` field. If two `Person` objects have the same `id`, `name` and `age`, then they're modelling the same person.

Comment: If they have the same `name` and `age, but a different `id`, then they're similar, but not identical. This `id` field needs to be present to give identity, rather than abusing the object's pointer value, because the `id` field is something that could actually be persisted, transmitted, etc. Reference identity isn't portable between machine, so it's a complete non-starter. I could have one thing at memory address `0x1234`, and you could have another object at the same address `0x1234`. If that were the case, how are we supposed to interoperate?